# Converting VIM text file to .doc or .docx

Tags: bash, vim

Scenario:

I type up a plain text file in VIM.

`vim some_text_file`

Question:

Is there a way to convert `some_text_file` into `.doc` or `.docx` format from within a terminal?

Comment: http://www.vclcomponents.com/s/0__/text_to_doc_convert_on_linux_using_php/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like

```
pandoc  -s -S YOURTEXTFILE -o YOURDOC.docx
```

if you have [`pandoc`](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) installed.

Comment: Error: "pandoc: Unknown writer: docx" ?

Comment: According to Pandoc, I should use "pandoc -s -S file_to_change -o new_file.docx" But of course, wouldn't have known about Pandoc otherwise, so I'll make this the answer.